React: ".map is not a function"
I am building my first React app using Java Spring for the backend. I encountered an issue while trying to fetch data from the API and map it in js. It gives me the error fireteam.map is not a function. Here is the problem code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const FireTeam = () =>{
  const [fireteam, setFireTeam] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/fireteam/id/${localStorage.getItem("fireteamId")}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {setFireTeam(data)})
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {fireteam.map(fteam =>
          <div key={fteam.id}>
            <p>{fteam.name}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default FireTeam

using console.log at the end of the fetch request to check the data gave me the correct data:
{id: 3, name: 'Intercessors', description: 'fdgdfsggfsd', killTeamId: 1}

So it's not an issue with how i built my fetch request. I thought it might boil down to timing issues between the fetch() and Javascript trying to map before the data was set, so i tried putting the fetch request in an async/await function and calling it in the UseEffect block, but the problem persists.

As Arnaud Flaesch has pointed out in his answer, the data from your API is no array so it doesn't have .map()

Hi. Welcome to SO. map is an array method - it allows you to iterate over an array and return another array with the same number of (changed) elements? Did you perhaps see this in a React tutorial and tried to implement it without understanding the JavaScript fundamentals of map and why and where it can be used?

Hi, thank you very much. I did see it in a React tutorial, and i'm not very comfortable with Javascript native methods yet. I'm just in need of guidance, that's why i came here.

Your data is not an array but an object, so using map() won't work.
map() is a function that only exists for arrays, just like filter(), reduce(), forEeach(), etc. That's why you have the "is not a function" error.
You need to either make sure you api sends an array, like this :
[{id: 3, name: 'Intercessors', description: 'fdgdfsggfsd', killTeamId: 1}]

Or if you're sure you'll always have just an object, do :
setFireTeam([data])


Alternatively, if they expect fireteam to always just be one object, then they can remove the array/mapping from their code.

Sure yes, I wrote that just in case but the issue seems more like it should always be a list instead of a single element.

Thank you so very much Arnaud! Setting data as an array has fixed absolutely everything, in the end it really was a problem of object/array type.

Your given example of the console.log is not an array. But the map function is used for array manipulation. To fix this you can ensure the data obtain as fireteam is an array.
The following code will do it.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const FireTeam = () => {
  const [fireteam, setFireTeam] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/fireteam/id/${localStorage.getItem("fireteamId")}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setFireTeam([data]);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {fireteam.map(fteam =>
          <div key={fteam.id}>
            <p>{fteam.name}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FireTeam; 


in case if you don't want to change type of data to array, you can do something like this
return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {Object.entries(fireteam).map(fteam =>
          <div key={fteam.id}>
            <p>{fteam.name}</p>
          </div>
         )}
    </div>
  </div>
)

you can read more here how it works

I don't mind changing the data type, but this is good knowledge to have, thank you.

Just FYI Object.entries returns an array of key-value tuples (e.g. [key, value]) of the single object's properties, so fteam.id and fteam.name will both be undefined. I don't think OP is wanting to map over the properties of a single fireteam object. This code won't work as you expect.
